# liquibase does not detect data changes

Tags: liquibase

by using liquibase diff with diffTypes=data on 2 tables in mysql data changes would not detected. In one of the tables I change existing entry and insert on row on a table this changes are not detected by liquibase. Changes on structure no problem.

Here my liquibase diff call:

```
liquibase --diffTypes=data --driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/magento --username=username --password=password diff --referenceUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/marketing_magento --referenceUsername=username --referencePassword=password
```

changes are in the magento db

Here the result:

```
Product Name: EQUAL
Product Version: EQUAL
Missing Data(s): NONE
Unexpected Data(s): NONE
Changed Data(s): NONE
Liquibase 'diff' Successful
```

Regards, Karsten

Answer (score 1):

Liquibase doesn't support this kind of data differencing. It can output the data in certain limited cases - the main one being where a table doesn't exist at all in one database.

Because the primary use case is for doing structural change management, design decisions were made to optimize the performance of that use case. Doing row-by-row data comparisons is very expensive, performance-wise, and tedious to do correctly.